# Maximum SQL Queries per page

Tags: php, mysql

This question probably has no definite answer, so if it's considered subjective and, let's say *bad*, please feel free to close it.

Basically I am developing a pretty big web application (PHP), and it uses [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org). Right now it's under development and some things in the Database are really complex therefore lots of queries need to be made in order to display the pages (around 7-25 queries).

Since this is probably going to be a large-scale one, I would like to know what's the *maximum*, that is, sort-of a point that indicates that "You're probably doing something wrong and should optimize", number of SQL queries that should be done per page. I have a very simple caching system set up right now which reduces the queries ran by a single user to around 5 for 15 seconds.

Is running 25 queries a lot? Should I stop the development (I have plenty of time) for a while and refactor the code, remove SQL Queries that are not used, and dedicate time to improve performance on this part?

This probably sounds a little confusing, so resumed: Is there a *de facto* maximum for the number of queries ran per page that does not hammer a server (that is, a shared hosting environment)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The total number of hits to your database is also proportional to the number of page views.  So if page views * queries per page is more than the capacity of your database, then you've got a problem.  Obviously traffic varies very widely from site to site, as does database capacity, so there really can't be a number to aim for.

Comment: what do you mean by "the capacity of your database" how do you define or find out this information?

Comment: @Ashley:  I mean the capacity of your database to perform the queries.  A database is capable of performing some average number of queries per minute.  If you attempt to go above this limit, most likely, things will start timing out.  I don't know if there's a well defined way to determine it, but you can test it yourself by unleashing a barrage of traffic on your database to see how much it can handle.

Answer (score 8):

The most important thing is not the number, but the expense of the query...

Running 100 `SELECT name FROM foo WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1` will be a whole lot better than running 1 of the following:

```
SELECT *
    FROM foo AS a
    JOIN bar AS b
    JOIN car AS c
    WHERE a.col LIKE '%f%' OR b.col LIKE '%b%' OR c.col LIKE '%b%'
```

So don't fret the number unless it's absurd (Over 100 is high.  Several thousand are absurd)...  Don't forget that you can enable MySQL's Query Cache...  So even if you are hitting a lot of queries per second, as long as there are not a ton of updates, most of them will be directly cache results..

Answer (score 4):

As recursive mentioned, there is no magic number. Far too many variables. Such as your database server specs. Clearly the better the server the more queries you can run.

Answer (score 0):

A possibly easier, and almost as effective method of optimization would be to batch queries where it is possible. This way you're making fewer round-trips to the database server while keeping your existing logic (mostly) intact.